# how to denormalize kafka topics for elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash

I have two collections, users and transactions on mongodb, i've pushed them to kafka and now i need to denormalize them for ES ? I want to be able to analyze transactions per age or something like that. How can i manage to denormalize my topics, does that happend at the logstash level ?

Comment: Are you set on using logstash? A good option would be Kafka Connect (Debezium) to get from Mongo and Kafka Connect also to push to Elasticsearch.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i've done, but the updates are pushed as a new line that is in a different form than the normal insert